# remove apache authentication

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to remove the Apache authentication from my web server. Someone just hand over it to me and I just really noob for apache and PHP. Here the configuration file:

- /etc/apache2/site-available/testing.local.conf

> Blockquote
>   
>               ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
>
> ```
>         ServerName testing.local
>         DocumentRoot /var/www/testing
>         ServerAlias www.testing.local
>         AcceptPathInfo On
>         AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
>         <Directory />
>                 Options FollowSymLinks
>                 AllowOverride None
>         </Directory>
>
>         <Directory /var/www/testing>
>                 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>                 AllowOverride All
>                 Order allow,deny
>                 allow from all
>         </Directory>
>
>         ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/testing.local_error.log
>
>         # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
>         # alert, emerg.
>         LogLevel warn
>         CustomLog /var/log/apache2/testing.local_access.log combined
>         ServerSignature On
>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

- .htaccess

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php/$1
> AuthType Digest
> AuthName "ggdev"
> AuthDigestDomain /testing
> AuthDigestProvider file
> AuthUserFile /var/www/env/htpasswd.dav
> Require valid-user
> php_value short_open_tag off
> ```

There are 2 modules are enabled on apache:

- rewrite
- auth_digest

I want to make to go to homepage directly without input username/password.

Comment: Remove all the lines beginning with `Auth…` and the `Require …` line from the htaccess. And go start reading the Apache documentation, so that you get at least a basic graps of what you are doing …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
Require valid-user
```

to

```
#Require valid-user
```

Run

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

or

```
apachectl configtest
```

and restart the web server

```
apache2ctl restart
```

or

```
apachectl restart
```

(There are other ways to restart the server)

If that does not suffice, put a "#" in front of  the lines beginning with "Require" or  "Auth"

Answer (score 0):

Simply comment out Auth(anything) lines, and Require valid-user line. then reload apache.

btw. it seems you aren't a person who configured this server.