# Test Sever asking for Username and Password when accessing to browser

Tags: laravel, server, centos

I'm new to setting up a test server for our development of Laravel+Vuejs project
for some reason when im accessing the server in the browser its asking me for Username and Password.
image below

[image]

I dont know what triggers this, if anyone can just tell me what triggers this i can probably search for solution

Server: Huawei Cloud Service

Operating System: Centos

hope someone can help

Comment: The directory is ```htpasswd``` protected i think

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove apache authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404124/remove-apache-authentication)

Comment: Look for a line like `Require user` or similar in your vhost config, or in an .htaccess file, and comment it out.